Prove: If $|g'(x)|$ is upper bounded by a polynomial, then $g(x)$ satisfies the polynomial-growth condition.
This is from the proof of Akra–Bazzi theorem p2.

$$
T(x)=\begin{cases}
  \Theta(1)&\text{for }1\le x\le x_0\\
  \sum_{i=1}^k a_iT(b_ix)+g(x)&\text{for }x> x_0\\
\end{cases}\tag{1}
$$
...

g (x) is a nonnegative function that satisfies the polynomial-growth condition specified below

Definition. We say that g(x) satisfies the polynomial-growth condition if there exist positive con-
stants $c_1 , c_2$ such that for all $x\ge 1$, for all $1 \le i \le k$, and for all $u \in [b_ix, x]$,
$$
c_1g (x) \le g(u) \le c_2g(x).
$$
Remark. If $|g'(x)|$ is upper bounded by a polynomial in x, then g(x) satisfies the polynomial-growth condition.

I proved as follows:

For the left part, I don't know how to get the exact value $c_1$ which may be $f(b_i)$.


But I follows the similar method as the proof uses in p4

Proof of Theorem 1. We first show that there is a positive constant c5 such that for all x > x0 ,
$$
 T (x) \ge c_5x^p(1+\int_{1}^x\frac{g(u)}{u^{p+1}}du).
 $$
The proof is by induction on the interval Ij containing x. The base case when j = 0 follows from
the fact that $T (x) = \Theta(1)$ when $x\in [1, x_0]$ (provided that we choose $c_5$ small enough).

Here since $g(u)$ is bounded, we have $\int_{1}^x\frac{g(u)}{u^{p+1}}du$ is bounded. So it is reasonable to "choose $c_5$ small enough" to make RHS very small. Then $\Theta(1)\ge \text{RHS}$.

Based on "g (x) is a nonnegative function" and g(x) is always defined when $x\ge 1$ implied by $T(x)$ definition, we know $g(x)$ can't be infinite by "$|g'(x)|$ is upper bounded by a polynomial".
Suppose $|g'(x)|\le p(x)$ where $p(x)$ are polynomials. Then $$|g(x)|=|\int_{1}^{x}g'(t)dt|\le \int_{1}^{x}|g'(t)|dt\le \int_{1}^{x}p(x)dt\neq \infty.$$
Then we can let $c_1$ very small to make $c_1 g(x)$ very close to 0. So $c_1 g(x)\le g(u)$.



For the right $\le$,


we have
$$
 \begin{align*}
   g(u)&=\int_{b_ix}^{u} g'(m)dm+g(b_ix)\\
       &\le \int_{b_ix}^{u} |g'(m)|dm+g(b_ix)\\
       &\le \int_{b_ix}^{x} |g'(m)|dm+g(b_ix)
 \end{align*}
 $$
Then I am stuck because we may not have $\int_{b_ix}^{x} |g'(m)|dm+g(b_ix)\le |g(x)|=g(x)$
Then I tried (Here $P(m)=\int p(m)dm+C$. This is still one polynomial)
$$
\begin{align*}
  g(u)&=\int_{b_ix}^{u} g'(m)dm+g(b_ix)\\
      &\le \int_{b_ix}^{u} p(m)dm+g(b_ix)\\
      &=P(u)-P(b_ix)+g(b_ix)\\
\end{align*}
$$
But now I still can't relate to $c_2 g(x)$.
It seems that we can let $c_2$ very large,
Then it means we need to show $\frac{g(u)}{g(x)}\neq \infty$.
Then
$$
\begin{align*}
  \frac{g(u)}{g(x)}&=\frac{g(u)}{g(u)+\int_{u}^{x} g(m)dm}\\
                   &\le \frac{g(u)}{g(u)+\int_{u}^{x} -p(m)dm}\qquad\text{when }g(u)+\int_{u}^{x} -p(m)dm>0\\
  &\text{Then due to both the numerator and denominator are bounded positive numbers,}\\
  &\text{the fraction can't be infinite.}
\end{align*}
$$
But $g(u)+\int_{u}^{x} -p(m)dm<0$ may be possible, so $g(u)+\int_{u}^{x} g(m)dm$ may be able to be arbitrarily close to 0 when $u,x$ changes.

Is my proof for the left $\le$ correct? How to prove the right part?

Your approach for proving the left part seems reasonable, but let's clarify and verify it.
For the left part, you're trying to establish that $c_1g(x) \leq g(u)$. You've correctly observed that because $|g'(x)|$ is upper bounded by a polynomial, $g(x)$ is not infinite. However, in your argument, you mention letting $c_1$ be very small to make $c_1g(x)$ very close to $0$. This is slightly incorrect. Instead, you should aim to show that there exists a positive constant $c_1$ such that $c_1g(x)$ is bounded below by $g(u)$.
Here's a corrected version of the left part of your proof:
Given $|g'(x)|$ is upper bounded by a polynomial $p(x)$, we have:
$ |g(x)| = \left| \int_{1}^{x} g'(t) dt \right| \leq \int_{1}^{x} |g'(t)| dt \leq \int_{1}^{x} p(t) dt $
Since $p(x)$ is a polynomial and $g(x)$ is nonnegative, $|g(x)|$ is bounded. Let $M$ be a bound for $|g(x)|$ for $x \geq 1$. Then we can choose $c_1 = \frac{1}{M}$ such that:
$ c_1g(x) = \frac{1}{M} |g(x)| \leq \frac{1}{M} M = 1 $
Therefore, $c_1g(x)$ is bounded above by $1$ for all $x \geq 1$, which implies $c_1g(x) \leq g(u)$ for all $u \in [b_i x, x]$.
For the right part, you're trying to show that $g(u)$ can be bounded above by a constant multiple of $g(x)$. The approach you've started seems reasonable, but you need to carefully choose the constants to ensure the inequality holds.
You've already established that $g(x)$ satisfies the polynomial-growth condition. So, let's refine your argument for the right part.
You want to show that there exist positive constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ such that $c_1 g(x) \leq g(u) \leq c_2 g(x)$ for all $x \geq 1$, $1 \leq i \leq k$, and $u \in [b_i x, x]$.
Here's a strategy:

For the lower bound $c_1 g(x) \leq g(u)$, you can utilize the fact that $g(x)$ satisfies the polynomial-growth condition. Choose $c_1$ such that it's the reciprocal of the maximum polynomial value bounding $|g'(x)|$ in the interval $[1, x_0]$. This ensures that $c_1 g(x)$ is a lower bound for $g(u)$.

For the upper bound $g(u) \leq c_2 g(x)$, you can use the same reasoning. Choose $c_2$ such that it's the reciprocal of the minimum polynomial value bounding $|g'(x)|$ in the interval $[1, x_0]$. This ensures that $g(u)$ is an upper bound for $c_2 g(x)$.


By choosing these constants appropriately based on the polynomial-growth condition of $g(x)$, you can establish the desired inequality.


One small error: we should say "$g(u)$ is bounded below by $c_1 g(x)$" 2. $M$ is one function of $x$ when $p(x)$ is strictly increasing. Then how do we know there is one upper bound for $M(x)$? 3. How do we have $c_1g(x)\le 1\Rightarrow c_1g(x)\le g(u)$? 4. How to get "the minimum polynomial value bounding $|g'(x)|$"? The problem says "upper bounded" but not "lower bounded". 5. I want to prove "polynomial-growth condition" instead of "already established ... satisfies the polynomial-growth condition" and then give one circular proof.


Thanks anyway for your answer. Hope you can clarify based on my doubts.
